# Handle InternetExplorer object events in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, events, object

I would like to handle within my Excel VBA code the events of the object `InternetExplorer`.

On this page you can see all the events available for the InternetExplorer object:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa752084(v=vs.94).aspx

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com"

While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Set mybrowser = Nothing
```

I would like to catch a `BeforeNavigate` and a `NavigateComplete` events, which the code above should trigger.

How would I set up my code to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dim` with the `WithEvents` keyword.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251750%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

> **Syntax**
>
> Dim [**WithEvents**] varname[([subscripts])] [As [New] type] [, [WithEvents] varname[([subscripts])] [As [New] type]] . . .
>
> **WithEvents**: Optional. Keyword that specifies that varname is an object variable used to respond to events triggered by an ActiveX object. **WithEvents is valid only in class modules**. You can declare as many individual variables as you like using WithEvents, but you can't create arrays with WithEvents. You can't use New with WithEvents.

Clmusy example `Class1` class module, for illustration purposes only:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents ie As InternetExplorer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://www.duckduckgo.com"
    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
Sub tester()
    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1
End Sub
```